# how to convert/read a XML file to text file using perl script

Tags: xml, perl

I have this small snipet of an XML file. I'm wondering How do you convert this XML file to text file using perl

```
<Root>
    <Top name="hello">
      <Module name="cpu">
        <input name="power_bus"/>
        <bidirection name="add_bus"/>
      </Module>
      <Module name="Pow_control">
        <input name="cpu_bus"/>
        <output name="power_bus"/>
        <bidirection name="add_bus"/>
    </Module>
</Root>
```

a general idea of a script I had idea about e

```
use XML::TreePP;
use Data::Dumper;
my $tpp = XML::TreePP->new();
my $tree = $tpp->parsefile( "family.xml" );
my $text = Dumper( $tree );
print $text;
```

Comment: Where is the script?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I have the general script attached @serenesat .

Comment: So like, copy .xml to .txt, is that it?

Comment: yeah that's correct @CorexCain

Comment: I'm just expecting to convert the xml file to a text file! with the XML inputs into a text file  @choroba

Comment: [File::Copy](http://p3rl.org/File::Copy)

Comment: @GRD: So you copied your code from [here](http://webdesign.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/perl-l/how-can-i-convert-xml-file-to-text-file-using-perl-script-2171027). ;)

Comment: @ serenesat :) that's true :) ! I wasn't sure about the structure though so got it from that link ! I have to actually extract those xml file data and write a perl script which can be used to convert it into, for example a .txt file or .v file or .sv file! that's the main objective! I'm not sure where to start, so working on that!

Comment: As @choroba has suggested use `File::Copy` module.

Comment: @serenesat I'll try that then